# Do memories cease to exist?

Tags: memory

Do memories ever cease to exist?

For example, did the memories I had 20 years go (which I can't remember) disappear? If a machine that could access and show memories existed, could it bring back those 20 year old memories, or are they gone for ever?

Comment: Bunch more duplicates listed in the comments for this question: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/11060/7001